# iostream limit max number of chars to read

Tags: c++, iostream, manipulators

Learning C++ with help of Bruce Eckel "Thinking in C++". Stuck in exercise 05 of chapter "Iostreams":

### Text of exercise

> We know that setw( ) allows for a minimum of characters read in, but what if you wanted to read a
>   maximum? Write an effector that allows the user to specify a maximum number of characters to
>   extract. Have your effector also work for output, in such a way that output fields are truncated, if
>   necessary, to stay within width limits.

I understand how to create manipulators both without and with parameter (which one is called effectors in the book terminology). But do not understand how to limit maximum number of characters to extract. `std::ios_base::width` specifies the minimum number of characters.

Shoud I do some tricks with underlying `streambuf` object?

Comment: Minimum? Looks like a maximum to me: http://ideone.com/o9dzcZ

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios_base/width/

Comment: *The field width determines the minimum number of characters to be written in some* ***output representations.*** Pity it doesn't say anything about using it with input.

Comment: With char arrays and std::string yes, it works correct. But what if std::cin >> a, where a is int? And on std::cin we have "234234234", then in the a there will be not first "maximum" characters, but all the input (may be overflowed).

Comment: I found what the standard has to say (C++11 § 27.7.2.2.3/7-8): *If width() is greater than zero, n is width().* ... *Characters are extracted and stored until any of the following occurs:
— n-1 characters are stored;
— end of ﬁle occurs on the input sequence;
— ct.is(ct.space,c) is true for the next available input character c, where ct is use_facet<ctype<
charT> >(in.getloc()).* This is for the `charT *`, `unsigned char *`, and `signed char *` overloads only, though. I don't see any mention of any field width on arithmetic types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not a perfect solution (but I can't think of another way at the moment without reading the iostream library).

Say you manipulator is:

```
class MaxFieldSize {/*STUFF*/};
```

When you write the stream operator(s) you write a slightly funky one that does not return an actual stream (but rather returns a stream with a wrapper around it).

```
MaxFieldWdithStream operator<<(std::ostream&, MaxFieldSize const& manip);
```

Now you overload all the stream operator of this class to truncate their input before returning a normal stream object.

```
class MaxFieldWithStream { std::ostream& printTruncatedData(std::string& value);};
```

Then all you need is the generic overloads:

```
template<typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(MaxFieldWithStream& mfwstream, T const& value)
{
    std::stringstream  trunStream;
    trunStream << value;

    return mfwstream.printTruncatedData(trunStream.substr(0, mfwstream.widthNeeded));
}
// You will probably need another overload for io-manipulators.
```

I would also add a conversion operator that converts MaxFieldWithStream to std::iostream automatically so that if it is passed to a function it still behaves like a stream (though it will loose its max width property).

```
class MaxFieldWithStream
{
    std::ostream& printTruncatedData(std::string& value);};
    operator st::ostream&() const { return BLABLAVLA;}
};
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;    
class fixW{
    char* chrP;
    char str[1024];
    size_t Max;
    public:
    fixW(char* p,size_t m=25):chrP(p),Max(m){}

    friend istream& operator >>(istream& is,fixW fw){
        is >>fw.str;
        size_t n=strlen(fw.str);
        cout <<" n= "<<n << endl;
        if(n>=25){
            fw.str[fw.Max]='\0';
        }

        strcpy(fw.chrP,fw.str);
        return is;
    }

    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, fixW fw){
        for(size_t i= 0; i<fw.Max; ++i){
            fw.str[i] = fw.chrP[i];
        }

        fw.str[fw.Max]='\0';
        return os <<fw.str;
    }
};
int main(){
    char s[80];
    cin >> fixW(s,25);
    cout << s << endl;
    cout << fixW(s,10)<<endl;
    cout << s <<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: can you comment on your code and speak to how it resolves the question's issue?